# SqlCommandBuilder Update Command is Generating Command but Not Updating Database From DataGridView

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am inheriting a form class (Form1) for Form 2. Form 1 code works without error. In Form 1, I use `SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand` to generate the update command for my Datagrid to pass to SQL data table which again works perfectly and the table is updated successfully. The SQL command text for Form 1 Update is shown here:

[image: Image 1]

In Form 2, I write the following for the update command, where the only difference is Selecting the Table shown here:

```
SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM dtbRateVerse;")
SQL.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand
MsgBox(SQL.DBDA.UpdateCommand.CommandText)
SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)
```

The command text for this update command is shown here:

[image: Image 2]

It is not dissimilar to the successful update command shown in Form1 (image 1). Still, no data is passed to the SQL from the Gridview.

I also tried writing a dynamic Update statement without using the command builder shown below. The text of this statement generates an accurate SQL command but again, nothing passed to the database. This code is shown here:

```vb
For i = 1 To colEnd
    colName.Add("[" & DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText.ToString & "]")
Next
For i = 1 To colEnd
    For y = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For n = 1 To colEnd
            gridVals.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(n).Value.ToString)
        Next
        With Me.DataGridView1
            SQL.AddParam("@PrimKey", .Rows(y).Cells(0))
            cmdUpdate = "UPDATE " & tbl_Name & " SET " & colName.Item(i - 1) & "=" & gridVals.Item(i - 1) & " WHERE ID=@PrimKey;"
            SQL.ExecQuery(cmdUpdate)
        End With
    Next
Next
```

If anyone has any ideas/ solutions on what I need to do to get the update command working properly, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Added ExecQuery methdod per request below:

```vb
Public Class SQLControl
    Private DBConnect As New SqlConnection("SERVER STRING HERE")
    Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

    'DB DATA
    Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    'QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    'QUERY STATISTICS
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    'ALLOW CONNECTION STRING OVERRIDE
    Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)
        DBConnect = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    End Sub

    'EXECUTE QUERY SUB
    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        'RESET QUERY STATS
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try
            DBConnect.Open()
            'CREATE DATABASE COMMAND
            DBCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, DBConnect)

            'LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND

            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p)) 'LAMBDA EXPRESSION

            'CLEAR PARAMS LIST
            Params.Clear()

            'EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATASET
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'CAPTURE ERROR
            Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message
        Finally
            'CLOSE CONNECTION
            If DBConnect.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBConnect.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

    'ADD PARAMS

    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    'ERROR CHECKING
    Public Function HasException(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Exception) Then Return False
        If Report = True Then MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Exception:")
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Assuming your code runs without any errors i.e. it simply does not produce the desired result. What you need to do is to capture the actual queries being run (including parameter values), so that you can run them in SQL Server directly. The tool for this is SQL Server Profiler. Once you get the actual queries you can inspect parameters and/or run them from SSMS.

Comment: Get the command and try to run it directly using SSMS and see if it is succeeding. What I think is your UPDATE statement is having so many conditions and due to that it is not meeting any row for updating.

Comment: There is no point to calling `GetUpdateCommand`. All you need to do is create the command builder and call `Update` on the data adapter. That's it.

Comment: When you take a screenshot, please only capture what is relevant. We don't need to see a whole bunch of empty space.

Comment: By the looks of that SQL, you need to redesign your database. It appears to be screaming for at least one extra table. Having a column for each year is almost always a bad thing and you should actually have a row for each year in a separate table.

Comment: @jmcilhinney appreciate the advice. I'll rethink structure of the database. For the sake of this problem, let's assume years are some other category item. Would any of these issues cause the Update statement to be generated improperly considering the successful update query in Form1?

Comment: Can you show your `ExecQuery` method? I've seen a lot of people using DALs like yours and, in my opinion, they're garbage. They don't especially simplify data access but they do obfuscate issues.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sure thing. Added in body. I got it this one from VB Toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be as I suspected it was. Here's for code from the form:

```vb
SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM dtbRateVerse;")
SQL.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand
SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)
```

In that, you first call `ExeQuery` and finally call `Update` on the data adapter and pass the `DBDT` `DataTable`. In your `ExecQuery` method, you have this:

```vb
DBDT = New DataTable
DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
```

That means that the first code snippet is going to be calling `Update` and passing a `DataTable` that was just freshly created and populated. Why would you expect that `DataTable` to have any changes in it to save? This is an example of why I think DAL classes like this are garbage.

If you're going to be using a class like that then you should be creating a command builder inside it when you create the data adapter, e.g.

```vb
'DB DATA
Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
Public DBCB As SqlCommandBuilder
Public DBDT As DataTable
```

and:

```vb
'EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATASET
DBDT = New DataTable
DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
DBCB = New SqlCommandBuilder(DBDA)
RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
```

Now there's no need to call `ExecQuery` again or create your own command builder. Just call `ExecQuery` once when you want the data, get the populated `DataTable`, use it and then call `Update` on the data adapter and pass that `DataTable` when it's time to save.

That said, you don't even necessarily need to change that class. If you already have an instance and you already called `ExecQuery` then it already contains the data adapter and the `DataTable`. You can still create your own command builder if you want but just don't call `ExecQuery` again and lose the objects you already had. If you changed that first code snippet to this:

```vb
Dim commandBuilder As New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA)

SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)
```

Then it would work, assuming that you are using the same `SQLControl` instance as you used to get the data in the first place.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks a ton! That was super thorough and just what I needed. Really appreciate your time and brain.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLControl` class is the brain child of VBToolbox user. It is a good tool, once created, just simply use it and not have to worry about all complicated setups that normally associated with SQL data connection. Besides, it makes the solution much cleaner & simpler.

There is no need to modify `SQLControl` class, when you need to update the changes, simply:

```
'SAVE UPDATES TO DATABASE
    SQL.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand     'Need primary key in SEL statement
    SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)
```

and refresh the DataGridview afterwards.